# can a kinect Camera for x-box support developing?

Tags: kinect-sdk

Can a kinect camera for x-box support me to develop an application? i am not sure for that because it is used for x-box.

Comment: Please accept the answer I have provided if it suits your needs or leave a comment to clarify if further assistance is needed.

Comment: That is the last time I answer for a user named 'user########'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. I have used it for this for months now. If by develop an application you mean a C# or C++ then yes, you can get the drivers if you download the Kinect for Windows SDK.

I am told you can also get drivers for Linux using OpenNI if that is what you are looking for. The only nuance is that if you want to compile to a standalone EXE you must pay for a license to the Kinect for Windows SDK development team. However, since you only asked if you could develop, the answer is yes. Also, there is a depth limitation placed on the Kinect for Xbox that is not present on the Kinect for Windows.